# Memory leak in infinite loop

Tags: c, memory-leaks, infinite-loop

What are the damages in your computer if you run a program which continuously generates memory leaks ?

For example:

```
while(true)
{
    char* c = malloc(sizeof(char));
    c = NULL;
}
```

then let that code execute for hours or days?

Comment: It all depends on the operating system. It may kill your process when the memory runs out, or it may kill a *random* process.

Comment: Why could it kill a random process ?

Comment: Because it may at first consider that the process needs main memory to perform it's task. So obviously less prioritized tasks will be stopped and the high memory demanding process will be allocated that free memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably wouldn't get the chance of running it a day. The unallocated main memory will  quickly reach a threshold level when the system will stop your program. The operating system in most of the cases would stop the process and at that moment system will run slow. The worst part is -**allocated memory cannot be used because the reference to it has been lost**.

**Note:** This memory leaked is not permanently lost. The system after termination of the program resets the available physical memory. Not the memory of hard disk drive.

Comment: So the allocated memory will be permanently lost. Will the hard drive (or the current memory storage) permanently lose massive quantity of memory ?

Comment: Will any OS reset the available physical memory ?

Comment: @Brainless.: Yes! after the process is killed the memory allocated to the process is freed and added to the free memory pool.